# Как реализовать push-уведомления?

Tags: android, push-уведомления

Моя программа работает на ОС Андроид .Интернет-магазин, где показываются картинки в (ImageView) и информация о продукте. Я хочу сделать чтобы при добавлении новой записи в таблицу mysql посылать пуш уведомление пользователям для того чтобы они были в курсе когда я добавляю новый контент, подскажите с чего мне начать ....?

Comment: [HTML5 Notifications — уведомления одной строкой](https://tproger.ru/articles/html5-notifications-is-easy/) [Progressive Web Applications - push Notifications](https://habr.com/post/418923/)

Comment: Вам нужен [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) - с сервера шлёте сообщения в канал, на девайсах на канал подписываетесь и обрабатываете информацию из пуша

Comment: Нет, я хочу чтобы программа один раз за 24 часа синхронизировалась с базой на наличие изменения в базе и если есть добавление то выводила уведомление а если нет добавлений то не выводила уведомления.Надо как то показать что добавлен контент в базу не указывая какой и прописать обработчик который будет ловить это всё и обрабатывать . Возможно ли это...?